# Change axes in matplotlib imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

A newbie question, I try to plot some data using imshow as I need the interpolation options. I wrote the following

```
X = np.array(ARR1)
Y = np.array(ARR2)
Z = np.array(ARR3) 
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y) 

Z_min, Z_max = 1.e1, np.abs(Z).max()

plt.imshow(Z, aspect='auto', interpolation='bicubic', vmin=Z_min, vmax=Z_max, norm=LogNorm())
```

I know it would be more suited with pcolormesh but as I said I need to interpolate the data. Is there a way to change the axes values to those defined with the arrays ? Thanks a lot for your answer !

R.

Comment: Have you tried the `extent=` keyword?

Comment: Yup but as written below, it's not anwsering my problem but thanks anyway !

Comment: If your `Z` array is not uniformly arranged, you'll have to interpolate before you can use `imshow`.  Try [`scipy.interpolate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html)

Comment: OK thanks for the tip, I'll try it. The weird thing is using pcolormesh(X, Y, Z,...) does the job so I was wondering if something similar existed with imshow.

Comment: `imshow` is for evenly spaced data, `pcolor` and `pcolormesh` are for irregularly sampled data.

Comment: Ok, so the conclusion is that imshow is better suited for functions or evenly spaced data. Anything else should be treated with pcolormesh and interpolated beforehand using any interpolation procedure. Thanks for your help !